Amazon Selling Partners API - Process Returns and Returns for FBM
What are the endpoints or steps needed to process returns and refunds for FBM (Fulfillment By Merchant) accounts using Amazon Selling Partners API?  I can find information about FBA but nothing for FBM.
I have read through the API documentation and cannot locate what I need to retrieve orders that have requested to be returned.

You can call the createReport API and request one on the listed Return Reports. For FBM orders, I would suggest the XML Returns Report by Return Date or the Flat File Returns Report by Return Date. They contain the same set of informations, but in two different formats.
You will find both the Approved and Pending
Beware: when you ask for the report using the createReport API, provide both the dataStartTime and dataEndTime with the format yyyy-MM-ddT00:00:00+00:00 (note that time is set to 00:00:00+00:00). If you set any time different than that, your report will enter in a FATAL state and no data will be returned.
Finally, there is no way, as far as I know, to either accept a return or emit a refund through Amazon SP-API.

Thank you! I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure this out. Do you know if the FULFILLMENT_ORDER_STATUS notification is appropriate for FBM accounts?

No, that's just for MCF (multi channel fulfillment shipments). What are you trying to accomplish? If you want, you can join my WhatsApp community for SP-API Developers here: https://chat.whatsapp.com/JO6QqPiwOrSJuDAXfnyBA1

Hi, @Marconline. The api’s you listed above doesn’t seem to include the customer return comment. While the get_fba_fulfilment_customer_returns_data has. You know if this is possible for fbm to?
